# Javascript height statement

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

This is not working and I can't figure out where I went wrong:

```
<style>
* {
margin: 0px
}  

div {
    height: 250px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -130px;
  }
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onkeyup = function(e) { 
      var div = document.getElementById('capture');
      if(e.keyCode == 70) {
         if(div.style.height == 250){
             alert("Yes");
         }
         else {alert("no");}
      }
   }
};
</script>
```

++++++++++++++EDIT+++++++++++++

Ok, well this works fine:

```
         if(div.style.height < '260px'){
             alert("Yes!");
             div.style.height = '475px';
             pan.style.top = '-25';
         }
         else if(div.style.height > '260px') {
            alert("no");
            div.style.height = '250px';
            pan.style.top = '-130';
         }
```

But this doesn't:

```
     if(div.style.height = '250px'){
         alert("Yes!");
         div.style.height = '475px';
         pan.style.top = '-25';
     }
     else if(div.style.height = '475px') {
        alert("no");
        div.style.height = '250px';
        pan.style.top = '-130';
     }
```

What gives?!?

Comment: There has to be an event fired to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parseInt to convert the value to number:

```
var divHeight = parseInt(div.style.height, 10);
if(divHeight === 250) {
    alert("Yes!");
    div.style.height = "475px";
    pan.style.top = "-25px";
}
else if (divHeight === 475) {
    alert("no");
    div.style.height = "250px";
    pan.style.top = "-130px";
}
```

Comment: It's still wrong `if (divHeight =  250)` should be `divHeight == 250`

Comment: @Juan thanks, actually better use `===` as it's surely numeric - save few more cycles.

Comment: using `===` is irrelevant to the question at hand, it's a personal choice, I guarantee you no one will notice the difference in speed

Comment: @Juan of course no one will notice but it's still a better practice.

Comment: It may better practice, if you prove that it's faster, which I don't think is true when both operands are of the same type. But my point is that that is not what the question is about, and the most common practice is `==`

Comment: See this test as proof that `===` is not always faster http://jsperf.com/triple-equals-vs-double-equals/3

Answer (score 1):

`div.style.height` returns `"250px"` String rather than `250` Number, so your `if(div.style.height == 250){` condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to change it from toggling, to use numbers 1-3, which worked for me no problem.